# How to get value from custom backend menu

Tags: customization, custom-field, admin-menu

So, i have to put this `<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qMSxYtrZS-c" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>` into header.php line 305 as shows like this:

```
<div id="videoid">
  in this line i have to put that iframe
</div>
```

then save it, then it shows in front end, to do that, i made custom backend menu in functions.php that show simple form, and it's done:

```
<form name="kotak" id="lebar" action="" method="get">
 Put the video URL here<br>
<input id="subject" style="width: 800px;"type="text" name="firstname" value=""><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

now i have to get the value from the form, then shows in that line 305, then save it, then it success, im using this code to call that value in different file and folders, i know there is something missing, and surely not working.

```
<?php echo $_GET['subject']; ?>
```

Please tell me what to do to get it success, im trying to write my custom function, not using any plugin. best regards.

Answer (score 0):

you must put name of input in your `$_GET[]`.

`<?php echo $_GET['firstname']; ?>`

and also i think you must try `$_POST[]`

`<?php echo $_POST['firstname']; ?>`

Comment: change your method to post and try the scond one but i tryed first one and its was ok and worked. have fun.

Comment: i change it to <?php echo $_GET['firstname']; ?> , then i add in action="header.php" , it goes 404, i change action="/header.php" it goes The requested URL /header.php was not found on this server.
what is i'am missing? i try to google, i find that you have to use Advanced REST Client for Chrome ? because im using HTTP POST through localhost.

Comment: omg ! cleane the method and still u can get the value !

<form name="kotak" id="lebar">
 Put the video URL here<br>
<input id="subject" style="width: 800px;"type="text" name="firstname" value=""><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

after you use it for getting input value use this :

if (isset( $_POST['firstname'] )) { echo $_POST['firstname']; }

its sample.

Comment: it does not work, 
<form name="formvideo" action="" method="post">
     URL video<br>
     <input name="subject" type="text" id="subject" style="width: 800px;" value="">
     <br>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   </form><br>
   
   <?php
   if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $video = $_POST['subject'];
    if ($video == true){
     echo "success";
    } else {
    echo "fail";
   }
   }
this is the caller: 
<?php
   if (isset( $_POST['subject'])) {
   echo $_POST['subject']; 
   }
   ?>