# My connecting URL form in html to PHP does not work

Tags: customization, menus, admin-menu

as my previous question [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/276584/how-to-get-value-from-custom-backend-menu/276586?noredirect=1#comment410375_276586) maybe miss lead, my code does not work, what am i missing, i write in functions.php then, i call in header.php
this is my form in functions.php:

```
<form name="formvideo" action="" method="post">
              Put the URL video here<br>
              <input name="subject" type="text" id="subject" style="width: 800px;" value="">
              <br>
              <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form><br>

            <?php
            if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
                $video = $_POST['subject'];
                if ($video == true){
                    echo "success";
                } else {
                echo "fail";
            }
            }
```

and this is in my header.php:

```
<?php
            if (isset( $_POST['subject'])) {
            echo $_POST['subject']; 
            }
            ?>
```

my goal is: when i input URL, then it show "success" on the same page in admin backend, also when i refresh the front-end, it does show the video.

Comment: I'm confused, is this on the frontend or the backend? If it's the backend can you explain where on the backend? When you say it isn't working, can you explain how it isn't working? Do you mean it prints out fail? Or a white screen of death? Or a screen you weren't expecting?

Comment: this is on the back end, when i click submit after entering URL, it does not show anything fail or success, then on the front end, the video is not show up. which i don't know either if the URL is printed or not on header.php

Comment: Where's the code that saves the video? The question just has a form, there's a lot of surrounding code missing here, I can guess you're trying to make an admin settings page? `$_POST` only works when you make a POST request, so all your users will need to be submitting their page from the admin area, it doesn't work across page loads as you think it does

Comment: yes you are right :D, omg, i dont figure that out :D, thats my problem i think :D,

Comment: can you show me how to save the URL video string is please, sorry for newbie thing, :D i dont figure that out :D

Comment: so i have to make php code to save the URL that i write, then the header can call the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the cause of your problems is here:

```
$video = $_POST['subject'];
if ($video == true){
```

For example, if our subject is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ then the check is:

```
if ( 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ' == true )
```

And we know that `true` is not `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ`, so the check here is incorrect. What we want is to check if `$video` contains something other than an empty value:

```
if ( ! empty( $video ) ) {
```

I would also recommend placing the form handler code before the form, not afterwards, and using escaping functions on the output. Right now someone could put a script tag in the input box and execute arbitrary javascript on the site

Comment: you are right, but the input box is in the backend, so no one can mess around except the admin. but i'll give it a try your method

Comment: and also, if i placing the form handler before the the form, the functions.php is getting white blank, it does not when after, i already try yours, it is not getting success or fail, same result

Comment: That's a white screen of death, a PHP error is occuring and the server is hiding it to prevent leaking information, follow the standard debugging process to find out what the problem is